# What does `enablesMarqueeWhenAncestorFocused` do?

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to apply parallax effect when swiping between elements on collection view on Apple TV. I can't find any reasonable information how changing `enablesMarqueeWhenAncestorFocused` in `UILabel` to true affects to selection. I'm using "Adjust on ancestor focus" in `UIImageView` and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will scroll the text horizontally when the text can't fit in a label. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018-208/?time=1514